# jQuery Waypoints - Sticky Navbar not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to implement a sticky navbar with Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) on a Wordpress site I'm building. The idea is that the navbar should be located below the large slider/header img, and then stick to top when it reaches the top of the page.

```
 <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>



 <?php wp_head(); ?>

<style>
#menu.stuck {position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;}
</style>


<script src="http://www.chuckagency.com/wordpress-new/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-        ultimate/lib/bootstrap/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chuckagency.com/wordpress-new/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-ultimate/lib/bootstrap/js/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>




<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#menu').waypoint('sticky', {
  wrapper: '<div class="sticky-wrapper" />',
  stuckClass: 'stuck'
});


});
</script>
```

jQuery is adding the .stuck class to the navbar, but the scroll behavior isn't working correctly - .stuck should only be added when .sticky-wrapper hits the top of the page, but it's being added on page load.

What am I doing wrong?

Test site at http://chuckagency.com/wordpress-new/ .

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `#menu` element is already a `.navbar-fixed-top`. It is fixed to the top of the window no matter what. I'm not sure what you think adding Waypoints Sticky is supposed to do on top of that. It may also be worth noting that if you're already committed to using Bootstrap you might as well use Bootstrap's own [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) plugin to accomplish your sticky header.